# Showing that a specific function $\mathbb Z[x]\to\mathbb Z$ is a group homomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $\mathbb Z[x]$ be the group of polynomials in an indeterminate $x$ with integer coefficients under addition.  Prove that mapping from $\mathbb Z[x]$ into the group $\mathbb Z$ given by mapping $f(x)$ to $f(3)$ is a homomorphism. Give a geometric description of the kernel of this homomorphism. Generalize.

Comment: What’s your research effort?

Comment: Where you start when proving this is a homomorphism is this: prove that $(p+q)(3)=p(3)+q(3)$. Then prove that $0(3)=0$, where $0$ represents both the zero elements of $Z[x]$ and $0\in Z$. Then you're ready for the more interesting part of the question.

Comment: I know that i should prove that (f+g)(3)=f(3)+g(3) but I am having trouble past that and understanding the question itself

Comment: You should also prove $(f·g)(3)=f(3)·g(3)$. The kernel is an ideal of $ℤ[x]$, but it’s generated by only one element. Prove that.

Comment: @YACP Doesn’t mean she *should* also prove that’s a ring homomorphism!

Answer (score 2):

Let $f,g\in \mathbb{Z}$, say
$$f(x)=a_0+a_1x+\ldots+a_mx^m$$
and
$$g(x)=b_0+b_1x+\ldots b_nx^n$$
We can assume $m=n$ (if $m<n$ add $n-m$ zero-coefficients to $f$), then
$$(f+g)(3)=(a_0+b_0)+(a_1+b_1)3+\ldots (a_n+b_n)3^n=a_0+a_13+\ldots+a_n3^n+b_0+b_13+\ldots+ b_n3^n=f(3)+g(3)$$
Then
$$\ker=\{f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]:f(3)=0\}$$
is the set of integer polynomials vanishing at $3$, namely the ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ generated by the polynomial $x-3$. Indeed, you can divide an element $f(x)$ of the kernel by the polynomial $x-3$
$$f(x)=(x-3)q(x)+r(x)$$
where a priori $r(x)$ is the zero polynomial or $\deg(r)<1$ (i.e. $r(x)=r$ is an integer number), but putting $x=3$ in both side of equation you get
$$f(3)=(3-3)q(3)+r$$
from this you get $r=0$

Comment: You can assume $m=n$ (add zeroes), this simplifies the formulas a little bit.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg thanks!